# Mongorestore not restoring data from URI

Tags: mongodb, terminal, mongodump, mongorestore

Recently I was asked to restore a MongoDB database but all I was given was the following URI mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb

I ran mongod and then the following command from within my /usr/local/mongodb/bin folder:

```
mongorestore --uri "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb"
```

After running this command i get the following output:

```
2019-05-26T23:00:27.148-0400    using default 'dump' directory
2019-05-26T23:00:27.149-0400    preparing collections to restore from
2019-05-26T23:00:27.150-0400    done
```

However, nothing seems to have happened. This is the first time I do this and I don't know what is happening. I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve here. It reads like you want to restore a local database into the same local database, in which case nothing happening is what I would expect to happen. I was under the impression that the `--uri` option was intended for use targeting remote DBs.

Comment: I agree with the comment from rh16. Can you please enlighten us on what you are trying to achieve here by passing a localhost DB in the URI section to the mongorestore utility? Also, if the URI switch needs to be used while restoring from remote repositories, shouldn't you be using the --host switch to restore in this case?

Comment: @rh16 Hi thank you for your answer. I'm trying to import the testdb database to my local computer. I know the --uri option is probably wrong but I was told that I should run the mongorestore program and all I was given was that URI. Would you please tell me how can I accomplish this task?

Comment: @fhernan22 Not without more details. You might consider reviewing the [mongorestore docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/). In general mongorestore is used to restore a database either from a remote host (i.e not localhost) or from a dump file created using mongodump. Without a dump file or a remote host, there's not much it can do for you.

Comment: @rh16 I understand. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

`mongorestore --uri mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName --db YOUR_DB_NAME YOUR_TARGET_FOLDER/YOUR_DB_NAME`

e.g :
`mongorestore '--uri' 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb' '--db' 'testdb' '--drop' '../path/mongodump/testdb'`

Comment: is there a way to this in javascript "nodejs" ?

Comment: In NodeJS, you can do the following:
import { exec as childProcessExec } from 'child_process';
import util from 'util';
const exec = util.promisify(childProcessExec);
await exec('mongorestore --uri mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb --db testdb --drop /path/to/dump/testdb')